# Unable to start activity no activity found to start intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to open a splash activity followed by main activity. But i am getting the following error in logcat.

```
01-20 16:46:45.568: E/AndroidRuntime(29579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 16:46:45.568: E/AndroidRuntime(29579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cyoa.necroprelude/com.cyoa.necroprelude.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.cyoa.necroprelude.CHARACTER }
```

Activity code - Main Activity

```
package com.cyoa.necroprelude;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Intent openStartingPoint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    run();
}

private void run() {
    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.cyoa.necroprelude.CHARACTER");
    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
}    
}
```

Activity code - Character Activity

```
package com.cyoa.necroprelude;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Character extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.character);
}

}
```

here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cyoa.necroprelude"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.cyoa.necroprelude.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.cyoa.necroprelude.Character"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHARACTER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.cyoa.necroprelude.CHARACTER");
```

to

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(this, CHARACTER.class);
String CUSTOM_ACTION = "android.intent.action.CHARACTER";
openStartingPoint.setAction(CUSTOM_ACTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating an intent that opens another screen make sure it looks something like the following

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(thisScreen.this, newScreen.class);  
 startActivity(intent);
```